# Component refuses to connect with redux store unless it's a direct child of the provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, I have this react component and it works perfectly with redux while it's a direct child of the provider, like that:

```
export class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    //store.dispatch(loadUser());

    fa.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      store.dispatch(updateAuthState(user));
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/" component={CompaniesList} /> <-------This is the guy
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const container = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, container);
```

But once I add it as a part of the Home component the connect function doesn't work anymore and I get this error:

```
The prop `getUserCompanies` is marked as required in `CompaniesList`, but its value is `undefined`
```

The component in question is this CompaniesList and that's the code for it:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUserCompanies } from "../../actions/companies";

export class CompaniesList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    getUserCompanies: PropTypes.func,
    userCompanies: PropTypes.array,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.userCompanies);
    this.props.getUserCompanies();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.userCompanies.map((company) => (
              <tr key={compnay.id}>
                <td>{company.id}</td>
                <td>{company.name}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <button className="btn btn-primary"> Criar Empresa </button>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userCompanies: state.companies.userCompanies,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUserCompanies })(CompaniesList);
```

So I can't subscribe to the store if the depth in relation to the provider is bigger than 1?? Should I pass the store data somehow from the parent component to the child?

Comment: please read more about redux Provider component https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider

Comment: Which `CompaniesList` are you importing for use in `App`? The default export (the one decorated by the `connect` HOC) or the named export?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm importing the default export, that is wrapped on the connect function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, @DrewReese comment ended up giving me the answer. On the app component I was importing the default export, which was connected to the redux store, but on the Home component I was importing with brackets

so it was a simple import error